# Javascript .replace() with multiple calls, some with variables, some with plain text

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

**Code:**

```
var csMasterPrefix = 'CS_',
    cpMasterPrefix = 'CP_',
    csContentPrefix = 'CSContent_',
    cpContentPrefix = 'CPContent_';

/* ... */

$this.attr("id")
    .replace(csMasterPrefix,'')
    .replace(cpMasterPrefix,'')
    .replace(csContentPrefix,'')
    .replace(cpContentPrefix,'')
    .replace('ibtn','')
    .replace('btn','')
    .replace('lbtn','')
    .replace('img','')
    .toLowerCase();
```

**Question:** Let me preface by saying I've looked at the solutions that say to make your own "clean" function.  My question really isn't how to do that, but rather how can I make ***ONE*** regular expression that would combine all of the replace calls into one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using [**`RegExp`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), the choice operator `|` and the global flag `g`:

```
var to_replace = [csMasterPrefix, ..., 'ibtn', ...];
var id = $this.attr("id").replace(new RegExp(to_replace.join('|'), 'g'), '');
```

Don't know if it is the most efficient solution, but it will work.

Alternative you could loop over `to_replace` and do normal string replacement.

Comment: Note that this function is not safe if `to_replace` contains special characters like `(` and `[`, `.` (and others). Since an ID is not allowed to contain such characters, you're safe.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Yes, you are right. I didn't mention this because there are not special characters in the OP's code, but I should have...